# Hide Links Through Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using this Regex code to hide links from a PHP page;

```
$msg = preg_replace("#(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)#is",'',$msg);
```

Also tried this one;

```
$msg = preg_replace("#<a[^>]*(http|www)(.*)</a>#siU", "","{$msg}");
```

Nothing seems to work. Please help to find a correct regex?

---

### My String:

```
$msg = 'asdsadasdas

    LINK:
    -----
    www.google.com

    <a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a>

    [url=www.google.com]Google URL[/url]';
```

### It outputs like this:

```
asdsadasdas

LINK:
-----
www.google.com



[url=www.google.com]Google URL[/url]
```

### However, it should be like this:

```
asdsadasdas

LINK:
-----
```

Comment: `$msg = "Hello there <a href='www.google.com'>Google.com</a> and http://www.google.com there";` worked fine for me. Echo'ed `Hello there and http://www.google.com there` - Both regex.

Comment: You are echoing, right? Show a sample of `$msg`.

Comment: So can you plz help to find a correct regex inorder to hide all other types of URL?

Comment: Regex is not a strong point of mine, sorry.

Comment: @user2854563 are you trying to remove everything from `----` till the next `;`??

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: No, just want to HIDE all types of URLs from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This works for me:

```
    $msg = preg_replace("#<a[^>]*(http|www)(.*)</a>#siU", "","{$msg}");
    $msg = preg_replace("#\[url=([^\r\n\"<&\(\)]+?)\](.+?)\[/url\]#esi", "","{$msg}");
    $msg = preg_replace("#([\>\s\(\)])(www|ftp)\.(([^\/\"\s\<\[\.]+\.)*[\w]+(:[0-9]+)?(/[^\"\s<\[]*)?)#i", "","{$msg}");
```

Comment: @user2854563: If you want a oneline code then I will recommend you to follow the answer posted by nu11p01n73R. His code is far more better then mine.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex can do the purpose

```
/^.*\b(http:\/\/)?(www\.)[^.]+\.com\b.*$/
```

will match all the lines (entirely) with link in them.

For example see http://regex101.com/r/yQ6bY1/3

```
$msg = preg_replace("/^.*\b(http:\/\/)?(www\.)[^.]+\.com\b.*$/m",'',$msg);
```

will give output

```
asdsadasdas LINK: -----
```

Comment: @user2854563 I've tested this person's answer, with what you posted for `$msg` and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: @ImranOmer I thought of something like yours but couldnt get to a one liner